# How can I check which RAM replacement can I use in my laptop?

Tags: laptop, memory, compatibility, ramdisk

I've a `Nanya (NT2GT64U8HD0BN-AD) 2GB DDR2 SO-DIMM PC2-6400S, 200-pin`, Notebook RAM I would like to use this RAM in my old laptop Samsung NC-10 I know that normally is upgraded with `PC5300 667MHz SODIMM Memory Upgrade 4 Dell Latitude ATG (DDR2-667MHz)` but how can I understand which RAM is suited for my laptop and so if I can use the Nanya? Which parameters I have to look at?

Answer (score 1):

You state the laptop is damaged, but you don't mention if you can turn it on or off. I will assume you can still turn it on. If you can turn it on, I suggest you go to the website Crucial (search Crucial memory in a search engine)

They have a [scanner](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/systemscanner) which tells you what you have and what you can have.

In regards to parameters and compatibility, most motherboard manufacturer websites provide a compatible list. For example, this pages shows you a motherboard and lists the suitable options.  http://support.asus.com/QVL.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=1&s=39&m=P8Z77-V%20LK&os=&hashedid=J4TfLoZ8TXyFAkFb

However, this website shows the RAM is for your machine http://www.memory4less.com/m4l_itemdetail.aspx?itemid=1442036661

Comment: +1 thanks however my question is related to the compatibility, not to the damage of my laptop...

Comment: How can you tell that it suited from the last site?

Comment: The manufacturer part number, `NT2GT64U8HD0BN-AD`, matches

Comment: But where is the link with my laptop? This is only the datasheet...

Comment: The important parts are that both are 200pin, both are DDR2. In this case, they also match size, both are 2GB. Both SO-DIMM. The MHZ may also matter, but that depends on the BIOS (I think).